# New Top Bar: Move chat, blog, log out up

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Would the "StackExchange" button in the new top bar make more sense with the "chat", "blog" and "log out" links moved up to the top line where it would be right justified opposite "Explore our sites?"

Then, the rep count for the current site could be listed in the right column with the other site rep-counts?

I purposely am asking two questions in one as the second depends on the first.